# Problems with \clip

Tags: pgfplots, clip

I have a problem with the `\clip` command. I want to do something like `\spy` but add some labels etc. only to the magnified picture. Since this is not straightforward, I want to clip a zoomed graph with a circle, but this is not working for me.

Here is the MWE and the graph I could get till now:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{10cm}
    \def\width{10cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    
    \def\xmin{2}
    \def\xmax{5}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{20}   
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \xdef\Gda{12244}
    \xdef\aa{1.87}
    \xdef\reqa{2.67}
    \def\f{0.001}       % scaling factor for values
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot1,
            height=\height, 
            width=\width, 
            scale only axis=true, 
            scale=\sc, 
            enlargelimits=\enlarge, 
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            ymin=\ymin,
            ymax=\ymax,
            restrict x to domain=\xmin:\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
            samples=1000,
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\f*(\Gda*(1-exp(-\aa*(x-\reqa)))^2)});
            
            \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs: \reqa,1);
            \clip[draw] (spypoint) circle (0.5cm);
            
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For me and my understanding of `\clip`, only the picture inside the circle should be shown. It should be an 'easy' mistake, so hopefully someone can help me with this.

** Edit:**

I just add a simple drawing in PPT to show the result of this project, but now, the problem is, that I cannot acess the predefined center of the circle.

[image]

I also corrected the code and this is the result so far.

**MWE2**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{10cm}
    \def\width{10cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    
    \def\xmin{2}
    \def\xmax{5}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{20}   
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \xdef\Gda{12244}
    \xdef\aa{1.87}
    \xdef\reqa{2.67}
    \def\f{0.001}       % scaling factor for values
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \clip[draw] (spypoint) circle [radius=4cm]; %<- the predeined point (skypoint) cannot be read, since it is in the axis environment and axis coordinates were used. 
        
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot1,
            height=\height, 
            width=\width, 
            scale only axis=true, 
            scale=\sc, 
            enlargelimits=\enlarge, 
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            ymin=\ymin,
            ymax=\ymax,
            restrict x to domain=\xmin:\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
            samples=1000,
            xlabel=$\mathrm{r}$,
            ylabel=$\mathrm{V(r)}$,
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\f*(\Gda*(1-exp(-\aa*(x-\reqa)))^2)});
            
            \pgfplotsextra{%
                \global \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:\reqa,1);
            }
        \end{axis}
    
%       \coordinate (spypoint) at (\reqa,1);
        \draw[fill=blue] (spypoint) circle [radius=0.05cm]; %<- here, I labeled the 'correct' center point.
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\clip` is valid for future stroking. If you move your two clip lines before the `\addplot` you'll see the effect (PS use `circle [radius=0.5cm]`, the other form is deprecated and triggers a bug in old `pgfplots`).

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the fast answer. Is there a way to put the `\clip` and `\coordinate` into a `\scope` environment, since I defined the coordinates of the circle in axis coordiantes?

Comment: I do not know... maybe using `tikzmarks`. But I am not sure what is the final objective, this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you can prepare a smaller, contained example showing your problem?

Comment: @Rmano I added a picture for more clarity. My problem is, that I defined the coordinates of my circle inside the axis environment and like you mentioned, the `\clip` comand only works outside this environment

Comment: If you move the `\clip`  before  addplot but into the axis works, but well, the axes are plotted. What I meant before was --- why don't you use `spy` and ask a question on how to add the labels you want, instead of reinventing it? Otherways, you should do the coordinate scaling manually, and I do not how to do it...

Comment: @Rmano Thabks for your answer. I posted a new question here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586809/problems-with-arrows-in-magnified-window-using-spy)