# problems with arrows in magnified window using spy

Tags: pgfplots, arrows, spy

I try to add arrows in the magnified `\spy` picture using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49251/how-to-draw-something-only-in-the-magnified-area-tikz-spy-library) but could not scale this arrow using the `arrows.meta` library.

Here the MWE and the picture I got so far:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\small}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={font=\large}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=0.5pt}}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% define values

\def\height{10cm}
\def\width{10cm}
\def\sc{0.8}

\def\xmin{2}
\def\xmax{5}
\def\ymin{0}
\def\ymax{30}   
\def\enlarge{0.05}

\xdef\Gda{12244}
\xdef\aa{1.87}
\xdef\reqa{2.67}
\xdef\va{216.92}
\xdef\xva{2.07}

\def\f{0.001}

\def\magn{8}
\def\msize{2cm}

\tikzstyle{only in spy node}=[%
    transform canvas={%
    %   shift={(tikzspyinnode)},
    shift={($-\magn*(tikzspyonnode)+(tikzspyinnode)$)},
    scale=\magn,
    }
]

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \definecolor{darkorange}{RGB}{255,140,0}
        \definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}        
        
        \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={circle, connect spies}]
            \begin{axis}[
                height=\height, 
                width=\width, 
                scale only axis=true, 
                scale=\sc, 
                enlargelimits=\enlarge, 
                xticklabels={,,}, 
                xtick=\empty,
                yticklabels={,,}, 
                ytick=\empty,
                xmin=\xmin,
                xmax=\xmax,
                ymin=\ymin,
                ymax=\ymax,
                restrict x to domain=\xmin:\xmax,
                restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
                samples=1000,
                xlabel=$\mathrm{r}$,
                ylabel=$\mathrm{V(r)}$,
                ]
                
                \addplot[
                name path global=A,
                color=black,
                smooth,
                ]
                (x,{\f*(\Gda*(1-exp(-\aa*(x-\reqa)))^2)});
                
                \foreach [evaluate=\i as \n using {\f*\va*(\i + 0.5) - \f*\xva*(\i + 0.5)^2}] \i in {0,1,...,5} {%
                    \edef\temp{%
                        \noexpand \path[name path=AA-\i] (axis cs:\xmin,\n) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\n);
                        \noexpand \path[name intersections={of=A and AA-\i},];
                        \noexpand \coordinate (A1-\i)  at (intersection-1);
                        \noexpand \coordinate (B1-\i)  at (intersection-2);
                        \noexpand \draw[line width=0.125pt] (A1-\i) -- (B1-\i);
                    }\temp
                }
                
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ja}{0}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\vaa}{(\f*\va*(\ja + 0.5) - \f*\xva*(\ja + 0.5)^2)}
                
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\jb}{1}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\vab}{(\f*\va*(\jb + 0.5) - \f*\xva*(\jb + 0.5)^2)}
                
                \coordinate (v0) at (axis cs:\reqa,\vaa);
                \coordinate (v1) at (axis cs:\reqa,\vab);
                
                \path[name path=AA] (axis cs:\reqa,0) -- (axis cs:\reqa,\ymax);
                \path[name intersections={of=A and AA, by=A1}];
                \pgfplotsextra{%
                    \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(A1)}%
                    \global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/x}{\Ax}%
                    \global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/y}{\Ay}%
                }%
                
                \coordinate (spypoint1) at (axis cs:\Ax,\Ay+0.25);
                \coordinate (spyviewer1) at (0.625*\width,0.125*\height);
                
                \spy[magnification=\magn, size=\msize] on (spypoint1) in node[fill=white] at (spyviewer1);
                
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[only in spy node]
% clip this scope to keep it inside the magnifier
            \clip (spypoint1) circle ({(\msize/2-\pgflinewidth)/\magn});

%           \draw[line width=0.5pt/\magn, darkorange, fill=darkorange] (spypoint1) circle [radius=1pt/\magn];
            \draw[line width=0.5pt/\magn, darkorange, fill=darkorange] (v0) circle [radius=1pt/\magn];
            \draw[line width=0.5pt/\magn, darkorange, fill=darkorange] (v1) circle [radius=1pt/\magn];
            \draw[darkorange, -{latex[length=1pt/\magn]}] (v0) -- (v1); %<- here I tried to change the style of the arrow head
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The commands for the arrow seems not to work, so is there a way to implement it in the `only in spy node` environment?

**EDIT**

When I try `\draw[darkorange, line width=0.5pt/\magn, -{Straight Barb[length=1pt/\magn]}] (v0) -- (v1);` it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: I changed the style of the arrow head and now it works like a charme. So is there some limit to the head size of 'filled' elements like `-latex`?

Comment: I think that `-latex` is deprecated (it's in  the `arrows` library). Have you tried the `-Latex[...]` one?

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the answer. Yes, I had a deeper look in the manual and with `-Latex` it is working well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in the comments.